# SVNKit 1.8.x in Maven

Tags: maven, nexus, svnkit

Is SVNKit 1.8.x available in a public Maven Repository?

I have a Maven plug-in that has a dependency using SVNKit 1.7.8 and I have now switched my SVN Clients to Subversion 1.8, so my plug-in doesn't work any more. I can't find version 1.8.x of SVNKit as a Maven deployment.

The alternative questions is: How would I package the SVNKit 1.8.5 downlaod into my Nexus Server?

Thanks
Steve

Comment: Did you search at mvnrepository.com?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like from version 1.8.6 svnkit are now putting artifacts in their own maven repo as described in

http://svnkit.com/download.php (scroll down to Maven Repository)

I can't see this flowing into mavenrepository anymore (maven repository has 1.8.5), but this may have been due the their repository being offline until about a week ago.

We use an internal Nexus, so we just added the tmatesoft repository as a mirror and we now have the latest.

Hopefully this eventually flows into Central as that is where most people look first.

Answer (score 0):

Based on a search on [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3a%22org.tmatesoft.svnkit%22%20AND%20a%3a%22svnkit%22) it does not look like SVNKit 1.8.5 has already been on Maven central. Write an email on the SVNKit mailing lists and make a request to deploy it on Central